# "popover image" - having trouble re-hiding the image after it pops up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Hello I currently have a `button_to` and an image called `basic(1).png` I want to make a zoom in type display. When the picture gets clicked the bigger clone will `show`.  This currently works!! However i want to be able to hide the `cloned image` again when i click on the `cloned image`.

- How can I hide this second cloned image on click?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#background-image-basic1').hide();
  });
</script>

<div id="basic-1" style="height:100%;width:50%;display:inline-block;float:right;">
  <%= button_to 'javascript:;', :class => "view-popover1", :rel => "popover" do %>

    <%= image_tag("basic(1).png", :alt => "basic(1).png", class: "img-responsive ", style:"border-radius:6px;" ) %>

      <% end %>
</div>


<%= button_to 'javascript:;', :class => 'background-image-basic1', :rel => "popover", :id => "background-image-basic1" do %>
  <%= image_tag("basic(1).png", :alt => "basic(1).png", class:"img-responsive thumbnail-instructions ", style:"border-radius:6px;" ) %>
    <% end %>


      
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.view-popover1').click(function() {
            $('#background-image-basic1').show();
          }),
          $('.background-image-basic1').click(function() {
            $('#background-image-basic1').hide();
          });
      </script>
```

Comment: Can you give us the rendered HTML? The rails code doesn't seem necessary here, looks like it's just html/css/js issue.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Typo in event handler on click, should be `$('#background-image-basic1').click...`?

Comment: still doing the same when i change to `('#background-image-basic1')`

Comment: I got it to work by changing it to `link_to `

Answer (score 0):

WRONG

`<%= button_to %>`

RIGHT

`<%= link_to %>`